# Drupal 7 -- Webform: Posting to API

Tags: api, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I am using Drupal7, I have a form that I want to build that will post to an external RESTAPI.  Is this possible?  I have a basic form (FN, LN, email, pw, conf pw, agree to terms checkbox).  I want to post this data to an external API.  This seems like something many people would find useful, but yet I cannot find anyway to do this.

Thanks, M

Comment: Yes that is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have just been searching.  I cant find anything useful. Im not the best with creating custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module if you don't want to handle it in code: [Webform Remote Post](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_remote_post)